# Max-height and max-width media query not working?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

My site is responsive for width using bootstrap, but I'm also trying to get one section to specifically be responsive for Landscape media queries... but when I do the live BrowserSync, it's not taking into consideration any of my media query requests... Any tips are appreciated.

In my style.scss, does the media query section need to be in a particular layout? Right now I just put it in the middle?

```
@media all and (max-height: 267px) and (max-width: 667px) {
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#header {
    .name-tag-image {
        width: 400px;
        height: auto;
        padding-right: 20px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        padding-top: 75px;
    }

    .my-name-is-text {
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        margin-bottom: -20px;
    }

    #resume-buttons {
        .resume-header-button {
            margin-top: 15px;
        }
    }

    .btn-circle.btn-xl {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 3px 6px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1.33;
        border-radius: 35px;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your html head?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the important comment above by [ittus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303610/ittus)

> In my style.scss, does the media query section need to be in a
>   particular layout?

Yes, order matters. The usual cascading rules apply, so if you have

```
@media all and (max-height: 267px) and (max-width: 667px) {
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}  
...  
}
```

and later in your stylesheet you had

```
body{
overflow-x:visible;  
}
```

then styling of `overflow-x:visible;` would be applied at all viewports.

Also, a max height of 267px seems low, I think an iPhone5 in landscape would be 320, and most newer smartphones would be higher.

Good luck!